# MySQL database couldn't be restore after uninstall Wamp server

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

after I formatted my PC I tried to install wamp server ,I made a copy of data folder inside MySQL folder ,then moved the an database folder with ibdata1 file to new wamp data folder in MySQL folder.
but at the phpmyadmin I can't find that database .
the database is very important , how can I recover it?

Comment: I copied my data folder many time and it works ,but this time I dont know why/

Comment: A copy of ibdata1 is not the correct way to backup a MySQL database.  you might be lucky to recover data using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304708/recover-mysql-database-from-ibdata1

Comment: The correct way to create a backup is described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/8.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html  (change version in the top right to match you version of MySQL)

Comment: can u tell me where I must execute this command :mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /tmp/mysqldump-all.sql

Comment: In the directory where `mysqldump` lives ? (or from anywhere if that path is in your PATH), or take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082539/mysql-dump-on-wamp-server-using-php